# Connections between probability theory and algebraic topology?

Tags: probability-theory, algebraic-topology, soft-question

Are there any substantial connections between probability theory and algebraic topology? In particular, are there any current research areas in algebraic topology that involve the use of probabilistic techniques? Are they are current research areas in probability theory that involve the use of topological techniques?

This is an idle question that I suspect has no satisfactory answer. Nonetheless, I am asking anyway.

Comment: This paper might interest you: http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/adler/larry.pdf